# Create a search bar on my dynamic related List on an Account page that only searches in the available data of the specific Account

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to add a search bar to my Dynamic related List component. My list is the opportunities associated to an account but when I search for opportunities the results are across all the accounts in the org. Is their a way to only get the results of opportunities related the the account the list is on?
Apex:

```java
public class oppcontrol {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)
    public static List<Opportunity> getopportunities(Id val) {
    return [SELECT Id, End_User__c, Name, Amount, CloseDate, Market__c, Industry__c, 
    Segment__c, Transaction_Type__c, Account.Name, End_User__r.Name 
          FROM Opportunity 
          WHERE AccountId=:val OR End_User__c=:val];
    }
 

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)
    public static List<Opportunity> searchOpportunity(String searchString) {
    List<List<SObject>> opport = [ Find: searchString IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
    Opportunity(Id, End_User__c, Name, 
    Amount, CloseDate, Market__c, Industry__c, Segment__c, Transaction_Type__c, 
    Account.Name, End_User__r.Name)];

    return (List<Opportunity>) opport[0];
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```js
import { LightningElement,api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import getopportunities from '@salesforce/apex/oppcontrol.getopportunities';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex'
import searchOpp from '@salesforce/apex/oppcontrol.searchOpportunity'

const Columns = [
{label: 'Opp Name', fieldName: 'link', type: 'url', typeAttributes: {label: {fieldName: 
'Name'}}, sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'accountlink', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: 
{fieldName: 'Account_Name'}}, sortable: "true"},
{label: 'End User',fieldName: 'End_User_link', type: 'url', typeAttributes:{label: 
{fieldName: 'End_User__c'}}, sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Amount', fieldName: 'Amount', type: 'currency', sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Close Date', fieldName: 'CloseDate', sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Market', fieldName: 'Market__c', sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry__c', sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Segment', fieldName: 'Segment__c', sortable: "true"},
{label: 'Transaction Type', fieldName: 'Transaction_Type__c', sortable: "true"}
]

export default class Finalopp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track sortBy;
    @track sortDirection;   
    @track opportunities;
    error;
    @track cols=Columns;
    wiredOpportunity;
    baseData;
    @track searchString = '';

    @wire(getopportunities, {val: '$recordId'})
    wiredOpp({error, data}){
        if(data){
            this.opportunities = data.map((row) => {
                return this.mapOpp(row);
            })
            this.baseData = this.opportunities;
        }
        else if(error){
            this.error = error;
            this.opportunities = undefined;
        }
        console.log(data);
        console.log(error);
    }

    mapOpp(row){
        console.log(row);
        var UserName = '';
        var Userlink = '';
        if (row.End_User__r.Id != undefined){
            UserName = `${row.End_User__r.Name}`
            Userlink = `/${row.End_User__r.Id}`
        }
        return{...row,
           Amount: `${row.Amount}`,
           Name: `${row.Name}`,
           link: `/${row.Id}`,
           End_User__c: UserName,
           End_User_link: Userlink,
           Account_Name: `${row.Account.Name}`,
           accountlink: `/${row.AccountId}` 
        };
    }

    handleSortAccountData(event) {       
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;       
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;       
        this.sortAccountData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
    }

    sortAccountData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.opportunities));
   
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };

        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
           x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
           y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
       
           return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
    
        this.opportunities = parseData;
    }

    async handleSearch(event){
        if (event.target.value== "") {
            this.opportunities = this.baseData;
        } else if (this.event.target.value.length > 1) {
            const searchResult = await searchOpportunity({ searchString: event.target.value});
            this.opportunities = searchResult.map((row) => {
                return this.mapOpp(row);
            });
        }}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a WHERE clause to limit the results:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=True)
public static List<Opportunity> searchOpportunity(String searchString, Id userOrAccountId) {
    List<List<SObject>> opport = [ Find: searchString IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING 
    Opportunity(Id, End_User__c, Name, 
    Amount, CloseDate, Market__c, Industry__c, Segment__c, Transaction_Type__c, 
    Account.Name, End_User__r.Name 
      WHERE AccountId = :userOrAccountId OR End_User__c = :userOrAccountId)
    ];
    return (List<Opportunity>) opport[0];
}
```

Comment: I updated my apex class like you proposed but when using the search bar there is nothing happening should I update the JavaScript and set the userOrAccountId as '$recordId' somewhere in the handleSearch function

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I used to have a functional search Bar. I didn't need to create a second apex class.

here is the modified handleSearch function:

```
handleSearch(event){
        var searchTerm = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
        this.opportunities = this.baseData.filter((row) => {
            for (let field of Object.values(row)) {
                if (field && field.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        });
```